# Function to replace all non alpha-numeric and multiple whitespace characters with a single space

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to write an efficient function to use in a *calculated field* which has the following characteristics

- Replace all non alpha numeric characters with space
- Replace multiple white spaces with a space
- Trim and lower the results

**Example input**

```
A   B@#%$$C &^%D
```

**Example output**

```
a b c d
```

A normal regex pattern would match like so

```
[\W_]+
```

The following works, however I am not sure if there is a more efficient approach than using 2 loops ( *O(n2)* complexity at least) with  `PatIndex` and `Stuff`, `charindex` and `replace`

```
Create Function [dbo].[Clean](@Temp nvarchar(1000))
Returns nvarchar(1000)
AS
Begin
    Declare @Pattern as varchar(50) = '%[^a-z0-9 ]%'

    While PatIndex(@Pattern, @Temp) > 0
        Set @Temp = Stuff(@Temp, PatIndex(@Pattern, @Temp), 1, ' ')

    while charindex('  ',@Temp  ) > 0
       set @Temp = replace(@Temp, '  ', ' ')

    Return LOWER(TRIM(@Temp))
End
```

**Usage**

```
Select dbo.Clean(' A   B@#%$$C &^%D ')
```

**Result**

```
a b c d
```

Is there potentially a single pass approach I can use, or a sneaky method I am not aware of?

Comment: Have you consider writing a CLR function and using regular .NET regex?

Comment: @DaleK yeah it crossed my mind, it have to benchmark it, though my spidey senses tells me any marshalling it did might kill any results (though that is just a guess)

Comment: I expect you'll find that any lack of performance from using CLR will be nothing compared to trying to do this in SQL Server.

Comment: @DaleK Yeah, I am trying to get some benchmarks, though there is other complexities with CLR methods. Its been a while :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not able to test the performance, but the following approach (without loops and based on some string manipulations) is an additional option.

Note, that you'll need at least SQL Server 2017 (for the `TRANSLATE()` call).

```
-- Input text and patterns
DECLARE @text varchar(1000) = ' A   B@#%$$C &^%D'
DECLARE @alphanumericpattern varchar(36) = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789'
DECLARE @notalphanumericpattern varchar(1000) 

-- Trim and lower the input text
SELECT @text = RTRIM(LTRIM(LOWER(@text)))

-- Get not alpha-numeric characters
SELECT @notalphanumericpattern = 
   REPLACE(
      TRANSLATE(@text, @alphanumericpattern, REPLICATE('a', LEN(@alphanumericpattern))),
      'a',
      ''
   )

-- Replace all not alpha-numeric characters with a space
SELECT @text = 
   REPLACE(
      TRANSLATE(@text, @notalphanumericpattern, REPLICATE('$', LEN(@notalphanumericpattern))),
      '$',
      ' '
   )

-- Replace multiple spaces with a single space
SELECT @text =
   REPLACE(
      REPLACE(
         REPLACE(
            @text,
            ' ',
            '<>'
         ),
         '><',
         ''
     ),
     '<>',
     ' '
   )
```

Result:

```
a b c d
```

Comment: Interesting out-of-the-square approach. Ill test it tomorrow at work and let you know how it performs :)

Comment: @Zhorov I'm curious why you TRANSLATE to $ then replace $ with space. Why not just directly translate to space?

Comment: @CaiusJard, it makes sense ( ... and honestly I don't remember why). I leave the answer as it is, but it's a very reasonable comment. Thanks.